# Given a list of shapely polygons generate a tree of which polygon contains which other polygons with no repeats

Tags: python, recursion, polygon

I have a list of shapely polygons, none of which overlap. I intend to do certain operations based on their level of nesting within other polygons (union or difference) to generate one final multipolygon that represents the entire set.

As a simple example, see the image below in which four polygons labeled A-D are nested. I would want to difference B and D from A, and union C. Note that the level of nesting flip-flops it between adding and removing from the main polygon.
[image]

The main problem is to generate a tree representing which polygons are nested within which other polygons, without repeats (A contains B, but not C). My current method involves a lot of looping:

1. Loop through all polygons while checking if the current polygon is contained within any other polygons. If a polygon is not contained, then add it to a list.
2. The "not contained" polygons are the outermost members of the current layer (children of the previous layer). Remove them from the polygon list one at a time and search again (depth-first).
3. Recursively repeat until no polygons remain in the original list

Example of what I've tried, but the recursion is not quite working (contains five polygons in output instead of four):

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely import contains
import numpy as np


class Branch:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def add_children(self, children):
        for child in children:
            self.add_child(child)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.root}:{self.children}"


def get_not_contained(polygons):
    # Find which polygons are not contained within any other polygons
    not_contained = []
    for i in range(len(polygons)):
        con = False
        for j in range(len(polygons)):
            # Don't check against itself
            if polygons[i] == polygons[j]:
                continue

            if contains(polygons[j], polygons[i]):
                con = True
                break

        if not con:
            not_contained.append(polygons[i])

    return not_contained

# a box
coords = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]])

# several boxes, some of which are nested (nesting labels match the example image)
polygons = [
    Polygon(coords), # D
    Polygon(coords * 5 - 1), # A
    Polygon(coords + 2), # B
    Polygon(coords * 0.5 + 2.25), # C
]

def get_NC_tree(polygons):
    out = []
    NC = get_not_contained(polygons)
    for poly in NC:
        brnch = Branch(poly)
        out.append(brnch)
        tmp = polygons
        try:
            tmp.remove(poly)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        brnch.add_children(get_NC_tree(tmp))

    return out


print(get_NC_tree(polygons))
```

I'm new to using shapely, so please let me know if there's an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The solution that I'm using now is to find all children of each polygon (a child is a polygon contained within the current polygon), then iterate through the children and remove them from the parent polygon if they are the child of a child polygon. This is faster and doesn't require recursion.

Pseudocode: (note that the polygons need a container class to provide child tracking)

```
polygons = list of all polygons
root = outermost polygon
polygons.remove(root) # no need to check root further

# Find all possible child polygons of root
for g in polygons:
    if contains(root, g):
        root.add_child(id, g)

# Check each polygon to see if there are children duplicated at lower levels
checking_list = set([root] + list(root.children))
for curr_root in checking_list:
    to_remove = set()
    for c in curr_root.children:
        for g in polygons:
            # For each child polygon of the current root
            # Try to add additional children and track
            # for removal from the parent
            if c.root != g and contains(c.root, g):
                tmp = g
                c.add_child(tmp)
                to_remove.add(tmp)

    # We have evaluated these polygons and can now ignore them
    for c in curr_root.children:
        polygons.remove(c)

    # remove the duplicates from the parent polygon
    curr_root.children -= to_remove
```